# RequireJs doesn't work with mysql variable

Tags: javascript, mysql, requirejs, require

I have a little Problem with RequireJs. When i load the index.js of mysql as a mysql variable and create a connection with it, then it says: `Uncaught ReferenceError: createConnection is not defined`. This is the code i use it in:

```
var mysql =  requirejs(['mysql/index.js']);
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'myhost',
  user: 'myuser',
  password: 'mypassword',
  database: 'mydatabase'
})
```

The javascript code is in the index.js of the directory js. And i use it in index.html.
[The hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGbt6.png)

What did i wrong? I don't use the normal require because i can't call it with node and it doesn't work without it.
Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql is a NPM package so it uses CommonJS module format. It is possible to use CommonJS packages with RequireJS, please read more in the docs: https://requirejs.org/docs/commonjs.html